# Groovy ExcelBuilder - help to understand example

Tags: groovy, apache-poi

I'am trying to understand how this code [example](http://www.technipelago.se/blog/show/groovy-poi-excel) works. Unfortunately isn't commented at all.

```
HSSFRow.metaClass.getAt = { int idx ->
   def cell = delegate.getCell(idx)
   if(!cell) {
      return null
   }
   def value
   switch(cell.cellType) {
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
         if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            value = cell.dateCellValue
         } else {
            value = cell.numericCellValue
         }
         break
       case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
          value = cell.booleanCellValue
          break
       default:
          value = cell.stringCellValue
          break
       }
       return value
    }
}
```

Can some one please explain me

1. Why need to override the MetaClass.getAt() method? It's not used directly. How does it work?
2. What's the cellType, dateCellValue, numericCellValue etc (methods or variables)? Where are they defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to override `getAt` method but it's overridden to make coding easier. When `getAt` is overridden it enables using `[]` syntax when You refer to object as in this line of code `return row[idx]` (taken from the example). It's operator overloading, see [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading). Summing up it's not used directly via `getAt` but with `[]` syntax.
2. In groovy when `getXXX()` method is provided (no arguments) on object `x` You can just refer to it omitting `get` so: `x.getXXX()` is the same as `x.XXX`. `cell` is just invocation of `getCell()` on [HSSFRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html) object, the other methods are invoked on [HSSFCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html) object and exactly the same rule applies.